# ADF -GetMetadata show file exists even if file is not present

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a folder in which there are many files (txt files) ,I am using GetMetadata to check if any file exists or not.
so in data set I mention
[image]
but even if no file exists it give exists=true

[image: ![enter image description here]

How to dynamically provide filename ?as I tried giving *.txt but this also fail

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me by passing `*.txt` in `DelimitedText` dataset settings.

Steps I did:

1. Create a Get Metadata activity with **DelimitedText** dataset.
2. In dataset settings, pass `*.txt` to test all the files in the given blob.

[image]

3. In `Get Metadata` activity, select **Field list** `Exists` and click on check box. See image below.

[image]

Now just run the pipeline and you well get the desired output as shown below.

[image]